# TYPO3 News Routing working but still Hash and other URL parts visible

Tags: url, routes, typo3-9.x, tx-news

I have a problem with routing and tx_news in TYPO3 9.5. I have tried all the official examples, but the problem still exists and I can't find out why.

Id' like to have URL like:

```
...home/news/detail/project-lounge-movetia-2
```

But I get:

```
...home/news/detail/project-lounge-movetia-2?tx_news_pi1[day]=11&tx_news_pi1[month]=12&tx_news_pi1[year]=2019&cHash=8fd7057d32ae3e3810b76f0bf4a06e39
```

The config is standard:

```
routeEnhancers:
  News:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages:
      - 40
      - 54
      - 55
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - routePath: '/'
        _controller: 'News::list'
      - routePath: '/page-{page}'
        _controller: 'News::list'
        _arguments:
          page: '@widget_0/currentPage'
      - routePath: '/{news-title}'
        _controller: 'News::detail'
        _arguments:
          news-title: news
      - routePath: '/{category-name}'
        _controller: 'News::list'
        _arguments:
          category-name: overwriteDemand/categories
      - routePath: '/{tag-name}'
        _controller: 'News::list'
        _arguments:
          tag-name: overwriteDemand/tags
    defaultController: 'News::list'
    defaults:
      page: '40'
    aspects:
      news-title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_news_domain_model_news
        routeFieldName: path_segment
      page:
        type: StaticRangeMapper
        start: '1'
        end: '100'
      category-name:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: sys_category
        routeFieldName: slug
      tag-name:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_news_domain_model_tag
        routeFieldName: slug
    requirements:
      page: '\d+'
```

The newstitle gets correctly "enhanced", but the rest is still there (hash, id, etc) I have no clue why this happens. I read the manual about routing a lot of times, but I don't get it. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should contain little bit more as showed in their documentation

```yaml
routeEnhancers:
  News:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages:
      - 104
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - routePath: '/'
        _controller: 'News::list'
      - routePath: '/page-{page}'
        _controller: 'News::list'
        _arguments:
          page: '@widget_0/currentPage'
      - routePath: '/{news-title}'
        _controller: 'News::detail'
        _arguments:
          news-title: news
      - routePath: '/{category-name}'
        _controller: 'News::list'
        _arguments:
          category-name: overwriteDemand/categories
      - routePath: '/{tag-name}'
        _controller: 'News::list'
        _arguments:
          tag-name: overwriteDemand/tags
    defaultController: 'News::list'
    defaults:
      page: '0'
    aspects:
      news-title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_news_domain_model_news
        routeFieldName: path_segment
      page:
        type: StaticRangeMapper
        start: '1'
        end: '100'
      category-name:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: sys_category
        routeFieldName: slug
      tag-name:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_news_domain_model_tag
        routeFieldName: slug
```

---

### Unwanted params

Actually date params like `&tx_news_pi1[day]=20&tx_news_pi1[month]=7` are **NOT** default ones, which mean that you copied some TS snippet, which includes it or maybe some of your co-workers put it there.

According to [News' Humane readable dates documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/7.2.0/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Realurl/Index.html#human-readable-dates) search for `plugin.tx_news.settings.link.hrDate` node in your TypoScript and modify or remove it to get rid *date* params in single-view links.

Eventually, if you want to keep them, but with human-readable URLs, take a look into the [newest documentation of the ext:news](https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/8.3/en-us/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Routing/Index.html#human-readable-dates) which has a sample for proper dates routing with aspects.

Comment: Hi biesior, thanks for commenting. I have more code, I just showed the important stuff. But I edit my post now to include all Route enhancers.

Comment: Did you try to add `date-month`, `date-year` aspects as mentioned [in the documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/8.3/en-us/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Routing/Index.html)?

Comment: @Phil, see [answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57523969/1066240)

Comment: Thanks biesior! The thing is, the exact same yaml config works in another site. I can literally copy&paste it and it works as expected. So there must be something wrong other than the yaml config, but what..? Can the Extension Builder interfere?

Comment: Does other instance also uses [day], [month], [year] params in news?

Comment: No, there's no {month} or {day} in the raw url of tx_news on the testsite! So the question must be: Why do all these params appear, how do I get rid of them in the raw URL?

&tx_news_pi1[day]=20&tx_news_pi1[month]=7

Comment: @Phil, take a look into my last edit, section **Unwanted params**.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The problem was not the routing, but the raw news URL contained all the additional params {day}{month}{year}. The following SETUP setting turns this off:

plugin.tx_news.settings.link.hrDate = 0

By disabling it, the raw URl generated looks like this:
?tx_news_pi1[action]=detail&tx_news_pi1[controller]=News&tx_news_pi1[news]=486&cHash=

It works now perfectly.
Thanks to biesior for pushing me to the solution!